# SQL merge row values in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

TABLE 1

| CODE | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| AA | 21 |
| AA | 32 |
| AB | 24 |
| AC | 22 |
| AA | 42 |
| AC | 20 |
| AD | 27 |
| AD | 28 |
| AE | 29 |
| AF | 31 |
| AG | 45 |
| AE | 51 |
| AH | 33 |

TABLE 2

| CODE | KEY |
| --- | --- |
| AA | 1 |
| AB | 2 |
| AC | 3 |
| AD | 4 |
| AE | 5 |
| AF | 6 |
| AG | 7 |
| AH | 8 |

Here i want to transform the table in such a way that AB value is summed to AA without effecting its key similarly AG's value has to be summed with AD without changing its key as below. Table 1 can have multiple values for a single code. pls help or tell me the approach.

| CODE | VALUE | KEY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 119 | 1 |
| AC | 22 | 3 |
| AD | 100 | 4 |
| AE | 29 | 5 |
| AF | 31 | 6 |
| AH | 33 | 8 |

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish.  I assume by "merge" you mean "add", but I remain unable t see why you chose to modify AB with AA, or AG with AE: what rule connects these keys?   I suspect "Key" is involved somehow; can you define its role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression in `TABLE1` to merge the codes that you want and aggregate and join to `TABLE2`:

```
SELECT t1.code, t1.value, t2.key
FROM (
  SELECT CASE code 
           WHEN 'AB' THEN 'AA' 
           WHEN 'AG' THEN 'AD' 
           ELSE code 
         END code, 
         SUM(value) "value"
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY 1
) t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2
ON t2.code = t1.code
ORDER BY t1.code;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f5f9b73efb4da8598e4469beb816e8a3).

Comment: your query helped me in the i had to do little transformation to suit my case, i had to post it as i did added a few details, thought it might give me new approach and the previous ques was not editable it said me to post a new question. Apologies